# Deprecated mysql functions?

Tags: php

I have changed my code to cater the new functions of MySQLi. Here is a snippet of my code:

From:

```
mysqli_query("SELECT user_type FROM user");
```

To:

```
mysqli_query("SELECT user_type FROM user");
```

Although this now does not work, what else would I need to change?

Comment: `mysqli_query` perhaps ;-)

Comment: No, please don't use `mysqli`.

Comment: yep! However certain functions with `mysqli_` need certain modifications but that will get you started.

Comment: *"Although this now does not work, what else would I need to change?"* You need to post your full code, and not just one line.

Answer (score 2):

There are two main options:

- [MySQL improved](http://www.php.net/mysqli) (or MySQLi)
- [PDO](http://www.php.net/pdo)

The latter lends itself better to OOP techniques.

Answer (score 0):

Change it to `mysqli_query("SELECT user_type FROM user");`

or, if you want object oriented

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'pass', 'db');
$mysqli->query("SELECT user_type FROM USER")
```